# No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)

Tags: jenkins, execute

I am building using Jenkins and this failure occurs, how can I fix it?

Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_pipeline_project
[test_pipeline_project] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins4967678336165865839.sh

- rake
  rake aborted!
  No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

The document I referenced is the URL below.

https://travis-ci.community/t/no-rakefile-found-when-adding-travis-to-a-github-project/3520/9
https://nesoy.github.io/articles/2017-01/travis-ci

Comment: Please check whether jenkins user has permission to execute the rakefile

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback. By the way, I am the only user of jankins. I opened the rakefile. And I checked that there is something wrong with the rakefile, but I don't know how to fix it.